# How can I edit Ion Icon Tooltip Text in Ionic v5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, tooltip, ionic5

Like in password field, on hovering over the eye icon of ionic it is showing the text as 'eye-close' or 'eye-open' which i want to manipulate and make the tooltip as hide password or show password.